# Javascript - Filtering Objects out of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm running into an issue where when I pull information into my array "const testOutput", when I go to filter, the filter causes nothing to return. I think the issue is the "serverArray:" that appears within my array. Here's my code now.

```js
const testOutput = {
  "serverArray": [{
      "machineName": "test1",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "daysActive": 3,
      "daysLeft": 117
    },
    {
      "machineName": "test2",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "daysActive": 2,
      "daysLeft": 118
    },
    {
      "machineName": "test3",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "daysActive": 3,
      "daysLeft": 117
    }
  ]
}


console.log(Object.values(testOutput).filter(filtered => filtered.daysActive === 3));
```

When I take out the "serverArray:" within javascript fiddle online, it filters correctly. So I was curious if there was something I could add to my filter to remove the "serverArray" so that the objects can be filtered. Thanks!

Comment: `Object.values()` returns an array, and your array is inside it. Use `testOutput.serverArray` instead.

Comment: `Object.values()` gives you an array of all the values in the object.  Your object has one value, so `Object.values()` gives you an array with one element.  That one element is an array (the only value in the object).  So, you'd have to loop over `Object.values()` then call `.filter()` on each element, or do `Object.values(testOutput)[0]`.  Why are you even using `Object.values()` at all here?  Are you expecting more than one value in `testOutput`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `serverArray` array from the `testOutput`, filter it, and re-assign it. I added an additional property to the `testOutput` object in order to demonstrate "keeping" other existing properties.

```js
const testOutput = {
  "foo": "bar",
  "serverArray": [{
    "machineName": "test1",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "daysActive": 3,
    "daysLeft": 117
  }, {
    "machineName": "test2",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "daysActive": 2,
    "daysLeft": 118
  }, {
    "machineName": "test3",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "daysActive": 3,
    "daysLeft": 117
  }]
}

const { serverArray, ...rest } = testOutput;
const filteredOutput = {
  ...rest,
  serverArray: serverArray.filter(({ daysActive }) => daysActive === 3)
};

console.log(filteredOutput);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace
*testOutput*
To
*testOutput.serverArray*

Try

```
console.log(Object.values(testOutput.serverArray).filter(filtered => filtered.daysActive == 3));
```